# tab as like fileexploler

Tags: android, user-interface, tabs

## How can i put tab as like this at above..

i want this type of tab when i click item it show on above,can anyone give snippet or links..
and please tell brief if available how can i do this..
as show in figure the red rectangle  is there any android tools for that or library....
or directly i can do by code??

Thanks in advance

### Rectangle describe what i want

belove is image

[image]

..

Comment: you can have horizontalscrollview with click logic on each item.

Comment: @MohammadKhatri  can u give code snippet ??

Comment: I gave you the whole project. Look below bro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made a simple project for you. You should make it more beautiful as I wasn't focusing on that, just on the code.

First add these values to your **color.xml**

```
<resources>
    <color name="buttonGrey">#7A7A7A</color>
    <color name="layoutHolderStartColor">#F7F7F7</color>
    <color name="layoutHolderEndColor">#E1E1E1</color>
</resources>
```

Next create some background for the button holder and name it **gradient_button_holder.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="@color/layoutHolderStartColor" 
        android:endColor="@color/layoutHolderEndColor"
        android:angle="270"
     />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
</shape>
```

Now create **activity_main.xml**

*Note: I am using some images, download the whole project at the bottom and get them out*

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/pathHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_button_holder"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:layout_width="29dp"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@color/buttonGrey"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onBtnAdd"
            android:text="+"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/seperator"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/btnScrollView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnAdd">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/btnFolderHolder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Next create the **Utils** class

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;


public class Utils {

    private static final AtomicInteger sNextGeneratedId = new AtomicInteger(1);

    /**
     * Generate a value suitable for use in setId(int}.
     * This value will not collide with ID values generated at build time by aapt for R.id.
     *
     * @return a generated ID value
     */
    private static int generateViewId() {
        for (; ; ) {
            final int result = sNextGeneratedId.get();
            // aapt-generated IDs have the high byte nonzero; clamp to the range under that.
            int newValue = result + 1;
            if (newValue > 0x00FFFFFF) {
                newValue = 1; // Roll over to 1, not 0.
            }
            if (sNextGeneratedId.compareAndSet(result, newValue)) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static int generateId() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {

            return generateViewId();
        }
        else {

            return View.generateViewId();
        }
    }

}
```

And finally the MainActivity

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private LinearLayout btnHolder;
    private HorizontalScrollView scroller; //parent folders
    private ViewTreeObserver observer; //needed for the scroll to the end
    private Toast toast;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
        makeButtons(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "Folder1", "Folder2", "Folder3");
    }


    private void makeButtons(String... values) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(values.length * 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length - 1; ++i) {
            sb.append(values[i]);
            sb.append(File.separator);
            addButton(values[i], sb.toString(), true);
        }
        sb.append(values[values.length - 1]);
        addButton(values[values.length - 1], sb.toString(), false);
    }


    private void init() {
        setWidgetConnections();
        observer = scroller.getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // this will always scroll to the last folder (displayed on the
                // right)
                scroller.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setWidgetConnections() {
        btnHolder = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btnFolderHolder);
        scroller = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.btnScrollView);
    }

    public void onBtnAdd(View v) {

    }

    private void addButton(final String text, final String path, boolean withImage) {
        // Dynamic call to add buttons
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setId(Utils.generateId());
        btn.setText(text);
        btn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        btn.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                goToPath(path);
            }
        });

        //btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_button_holder);
        btnHolder.addView(btn, params);
        if (withImage) {
            ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.seperator2);
            btnHolder.addView(view, params);
        }



    }

    private void goToPath(String path) {
        showToast(path);
    }

    private void showToast(String text) {
        if (toast != null) {
            toast.cancel();
        }

        toast = Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }


}
```

This is the final result and also note that it is horizontally scrollable

[image]

You can download the whole project [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91522375/FolderButtons.zip)

Comment: great exert what i need here is my vot

Answer (score 3):

It can be possible through your code,

[image]

In that Linear Layout you have to dynamically insert another layout having an image view represents the ">" and the text view used to reprsent the directory
the layout would be looks like that sort of

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/arrow_image"
        android:text="Storage"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/textView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

While adding the View dynamically you just need to maintain the list of views added in account for clickevents, which would enables you to switch into the directories directly. And just remove that view from your view list as you move back to the previous directory, and that's all! you have made it.

and your code snippet will be look like this

```
final ArrayList<View> myDynamicView = new ArrayList<>();
//it would be your list item click
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View dynamicView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field_layout, null);
        dynamicView.setId(unique_id); // create a unique id to refer a view
        TextView directoryName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        directoryName.setText(your_directory_name);//Either fetch it through your array or by extracting the view
        myDynamicView.add(myDynamicView.size(), dynamicView);
        linearLayout.addView(dynamicView);
        dynamicView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for(int i= 0; i < myDynamicView.size(); i++){
                    //When view is clicked match the view id from the view list
                    if(myDynamicView.get(i).getId() == v.getId()){
                            //when view id got matched it means remove those view which are ahead of it
                        //from the list as well as from the linear layout
                        for(int j = i; j < myDynamicView.size(); j++){
                            View view = myDynamicView.get(j);
                            linearLayout.removeView(view);
                            myDynamicView.remove(j);
                        }

                        //update list
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        //update your list

    }
});
```

Comment: @AbhishekDabral Stop spoon feeding.. he need help not crutches

Answer (score 1):

This actually is done using [Creating Swipe Views](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) and updating the divider of tabs, or you can even customize the implementation by using `HorizontalScrollView` and adding a child when going in a folder and removing last child when going back.